# Moveit limited full joints explanation

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running the moveit launch files at https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot. The last set of instructions have the following instructions:

> As MoveIt! seems to have difficulties
> with finding plans for the UR with
> full joint limits [-2pi, 2pi], there
> is a joint_limited version using joint
> limits restricted to [-pi,pi].

Can someone please help me understand what that means?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318945/moveit-limited-full-joints-explanation/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to [ros-industrial/universal_robot#265](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/265).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0